# Making textures appear after an input

Tags: c++, sdl-2

```
void CChat::nextDialogue(CTexture* speech, int currentDialogue, int afterDialogue, int ticks)
{
if(dialogueClick == currentDialogue)
{
    speech->draw();     
    if(mainEvent->type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN && ticking >= ticks)
    {
    dialogueClick = afterDialogue;
    speech->goodBye();
    }
    if(ticking <= (ticks + 2000))
    {
    ticking = SDL_GetTicks() - 2000;
    cout << ticking << endl;
    }
}
```

}

Hi, I'm trying to find a way to make a texture appear on screen after I click a button, but what it does is that it only reads the input of the click and displays the texture ONLY during the input.

`Speech->goodBye()`

is from another class and contains and SDL_DESTROYTEXTURE so that it could load another texture. The code actually does what I basically wants, to load and and unload an image but it is very dependent on time.

```
nextDialogue(S1, 0, 1, 2000);
nextDialogue(S2, 1, 2, 4000);
nextDialogue(S3, 2, 3, 6000);
```

That's a sample of what I would add on the gameloop, S1 stands for the texture and the number on the end stands form the miliseconds the computer needs to reach before it would read the key press event since a single press could make a hundred digital presses and would result in multiple skips.

I've tried working through loopholes, making variables, using switches, etc.. but this is so far the most successful one though dependent on time.

The problem here is that if I fulfill the time requirement for the other texture then that texture appears, instead of the previous texture.

So does anyone here have a better idea as to how to make a texture appear after a user presses an input and makes it REMAIN on the screen until the user presses another input?

Comment: The simple option would be to use boolean flags and toggle between true and false based on input. Then you just draw the texture if the appropriate flag is true.

Comment: I already tried that but when I check using debug (since I used a bool and int parameter to check) I noticed that it does what I want with lightning speed, so it speedily renders the textures then moves to the next scene with the specified int, but it's too fast to be seen and thus, ends up useless. This led me to use timers.......

Comment: @Zammalad, thanks to you I went back to booleans, but the thing that got it to work was the additional timer, thanks though.

Comment: you haven't really worded your requirements very well. There should be absolutely no need to use a timer if you want to have a texture show when you press a button and then stay on screen until you press something else.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I finally got it to work, After some agonizing hours of half-hearted thinking...
It also uses a timer, but this time, it uses 2 timers.
Timer1 is initialized at the start of the function and every time I press a key DOWN then timer2 would equal timer1 then I check in an if statement that if

```
timer1 >= timer2;
```

then the texture would be removed from the screen, I also added an int which I named dialogueClick, this corresponds to the two other ints in the parameter which is currentscene and after scene.
dialogueClick should equal currentScene so that the texture would render, in the if statement that is associated with the timer, if we were to trigger an input then dialogueClick would equal to afterScene, this way I could branch multiple dialogues depending on choices. The first problem is that you can't just add 1 to dialogueClick because doing so would add numerous 1 as long as the requirements are fulfilled. I'm not on my laptop that's why I can't post the code.

EDIT: Here's the code

```
  void CChat::run(CTexture* speech, int currentDialogue, int afterDialogue, CTexture* 

character)
{
    if(scene == currentDialogue && notClicked)
    {
        speech->draw();
        if(character != NULL)
        {
            nBox->draw();
            character->draw();
        }
        if(mainEvent->type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN)
        {
            clicked = true;
            ticking3 = ticking;
        }
        if(clicked == true && mainEvent->type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP)
        {
            notClicked = false;
        }

        if(mainEvent->type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
        {
            if(mainEvent->key.keysym.sym == SDLK_SPACE)
            {
                clicked = true;
                ticking3 = ticking;
            }
        }
        if(clicked == true && mainEvent->type == SDL_KEYUP)
        {
            if(mainEvent->key.keysym.sym == SDLK_SPACE)
            {
                notClicked = false;
            }
        }

    }
    else if(!notClicked && ticking >= ticking3 && scene == currentDialogue)
    {
        clicked = false;
        notClicked = true;
        speech->goodBye();
        scene = afterDialogue;
    }

}
```

And here's a sample of what you're supposed to use in the gameloop

```
run(S1, 1, 2, Mom);
run(S2, 2, 3, Mom);
run(S3, 3, 4, Mom);
run(S4, 4, 5, Dad);
```

(Texture, current scene number, the scene number that scene moves to after it's done, and the character who is talking which I added to make the loop appear thinner)

I really hope this helps another person.

Comment: This answer is actually flawed, I removed the destroy texture but I didn't remove the timer since there are times when you don't want the dialogue to show up  in an instant.